# wp_editor with media buttons

Tags: uploads, media, front-end, wp-editor

I use `wp_editor()` on the frontend. media_buttons are displayed on default **if** visitor is logged in. I want to display these media buttons whether user is logged in or not. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve this

```
 // Displays media buttons in editor regardless of logged in status
wp_editor( $content, 'editorname', array('media_buttons' => true) );
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP asked to display the media buttons regardless of authentication status. Your code does the opposite of that.

Comment: @shea I have changed the code to do it.